# Deleting a Tab App from Page throws error

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

Deleting a Tab app from a page throws error.. I can successfully add the tab app, but cannot remove it with same credentials.

Unsure if it is new. I am pretty sure my data is correct.

Steps to Reproduce

1. Get on to graph API explorer.
2. Try DELETE for `/192869707423790/tabs/app_149874521847288`.
3. Throws error -

   `{
    "error": {
     "message": "(#100) Tab is not installed or not removable: app_149874521847288", 
     "type": "OAuthException", 
     "code": 100
   }
   }`

Comment: I'm encountering this issue, too.

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503381706394259).

Comment: Worked for me so could be a bug affecting subset of pages / tabs.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503381706394259 They say fix is ready to be pushed next Tuesday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed and closed now.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503381706394259